# How to search and replace xml snippet using perl code

Tags: xml, perl

I have this xml code snippet in a file which I would like comment out using perl.

```
<plugin id="InvalidObjectsCheck"
        description="Verifying No Database Invalid Objects Exist"
        invoke=""
        plugin.class="oracle.check.apps.InvalidObjectsCheckPlugin"
        class.path="$HC_LOCATION/lib/precheckplugin.jar;
                    $HC_LOCATION/lib/hccommon.jar;
                    $APPLICATIONS_BASE/fusionapps/applications/lcm/ad/java/adjava.jar"
        stoponerror="false"/>
```

Unfortunately the closing tag (stoponerror="false"/>) for other DTD also. I have written a subroutine for this but not sure how to proceed once I read the entire contents of the file.

```
sub skip_lp_hc($skiplphc)
    {
        $hcfile = "${sharedStorageLoc}${fs}${podName}${fs}${releaseTo}${fs}fusionapps${fs}applications${fs}lcm${fs}hc${fs}config${fs}ga${fs}GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml";
        if(! -e "$hcfile")
        {
            print "[ERROR]: Unable to locate the manifest file : GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
            print "[INFO] : Located at ${sharedStorageLoc}${fs}${podName}${fs}${releaseTo}${fs}fusionapps${fs}applications${fs}lcm${fs}hc${fs}config${fs}ga\n";
        }
        if($skiplphc eq true)
        {
            print "[SUCCESS] : Able to access GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
            print "[INFO] : ${sharedStorageLoc}${fs}${podName}${fs}${releaseTo}${fs}fusionapps${fs}applications${fs}lcm${fs}hc${fs}config${fs}ga\n";
            open (IN, "<$hcfile") or die "Cannot open the file : $hcfile\n";
            while (my $my_line = <IN> )
                {
                        chomp $my_line;
                        $my_line =~ s/^\s+//;
                        $my_line =~ s/\s+$//;
                        if ($my_line =~ m/<plugin id="InvalidObjectsCheck"\=(.*)/)
                        {
                          print "[INFO] : Found a match for <plugin id=InvalidObjectsCheck            after accessing GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
                        }
                }
                close (IN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume `${fs}` is your "field separator"? That is not very readable. You should consider using [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) instead. Or if that is a path you are working on, using a proper module such as `catfile` from [`File::Spec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html).

Comment: Please, fill in the missing verb into *Unfortunately the closing tag (stoponerror="false"/>) for other DTD also*.

Comment: Also: `if($skiplphc eq true)` is a horrible way to check for a true value. `if ($skip)` is all you need, and using `eq` will make the check much more strict that it needs to be. And you've declared your subroutine horribly wrong, `sub skip_lp_hc($skiplphc) {` should be `sub skip_lp_hc { my ($skip_lp_hc) = @_; `

Answer (score 1):

I will let you deal with the insane file names, and give you a simple XML::Twig based solution that will keep you out of XML-parsing-with-regexp Hell:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { plugin => \&plugin }, # process only plugin
                twig_print_outside_roots => 1,        # output rest unchanged
                pretty_print => 'cvs',                # closest style to input
              )
         ->parsefile_inplace( "my.xml");

# called for each plugin element
sub plugin
  { my( $t, $plugin)=@_;
    my $text= $plugin->sprint;
    $text=~ s{;   }{;\n}g;      # slightly massage the output to get proper format
    print "<!--$text\n  -->";   # output element commented out
  }
```

With this you don't need to worry about the specifics of the initial XML and you don't even read the entire file in memory.

Answer (score -1):

${sharedStorageLoc} is a shell syntax, please use $sharedStorageLoc in perl files.

if($skiplphc eq true) is a shell syntax, please use if($skiplphc) instead.

sub skip_lp_hc($skiplphc) is not a good perl syntax also.

I think your real problem is your regexp, it has one extra = and it did not match.

I rewrited it a bit:

```
sub skip_lp_hc {
  my $skiplphc = shift;
  my $hcfile = "$sharedStorageLoc$fs$podName$fs$releaseTo$fsfusionapps$fs$applications$fs$lcm$fs$hc$fs$config$fs$ga$fs$GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml";
  if(! -e "$hcfile") {
     print "[ERROR]: Unable to locate the manifest file : GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
     print "[INFO] : Located at $sharedStorageLoc$fs$podName$fs$releaseTo$fsfusionapps$fs$applications$fs$lcm$fs$hc$fs$config$fs$ga\n";
  }
  if($skiplphc)  {
     print "[SUCCESS] : Able to access GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
     print "[INFO] : $sharedStorageLoc$fs$podName$fs$releaseTo$fsfusionapps$fs$applications$fs$lcm$fs$hc$fs$config$fs$ga\n";
     open (IN, "<", $hcfile) or die "Cannot open the file : $hcfile, $!\n";
     while (my $my_line = <IN> )  {
             chomp $my_line;
             $my_line =~ s/^\s+//s;
             $my_line =~ s/\s+$//s;
             if ($my_line =~ m/<plugin\s+id=['"]InvalidObjectsCheck/i){
                 print "[INFO] : Found a match for <plugin id=InvalidObjectsCheck after accessing GeneralSystemHealthChecks.xml\n";
             }
         }
         close (IN);
  }
}
```

Comment: `${sharedStorageLoc}` is valid Perl syntax. You can use curly braces to disambiguate. This: `$fsfusionapps` does not interpolate the `$fs` variable, for example, and needs to be `${fs}fusionapps`.

Comment: I know, but using everytime is not too perlish. This is why I said it is a shell like syntax...